# database stores the data more than once in django

Tags: python, django

im making a small site to learn django through book by it

so i made a database model named Writer

```
class Writer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20);
```

and i made a view(controller) to register the writers

```
def addwriter(request,name):
  nimos = Writer(name=name);
  nimos.save();
  return render_to_response("addJournalist.html",{"name":nimos.name});
```

and its url:

```
(r'^new/(.+)/',addwriter)
```

note: i know it should be done using post form but i made it that way because the book didn't reach forms yet.

when i access the writers in a web page:
view

```
def mainjournal(request):
   writers = Writer.objects.all();
   return render_to_response("journalMain.html",{"writers":writers});
```

template part
    {% block content %}

```
  {% for writer in writers %}

    <p>{{ writer.name }} and his id is {{ writer.id }}</p>


 {% empty %}

      good luck finding writers man


 {% endfor %}



 {% endblock %}
```

it gives me for each name i add three names added in the other view:

example( added george in web page):

George and his id is 22

George and his id is 23

George/img and his id is 24

i dont know why so im asking you why

Comment: You are getting 3 requests when adding new writer. Debug on those lines. Code that is creating entries looks ok.

Comment: how many times you add `George` ??

Comment: only one time that what im talking about but may be you are i may check the logs on terminal

Comment: im sorry i know now the answer i simply included static files for css and imgs by a wrong way in html so he made the request three times im very sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 1):

add some log to your addwriter view. Just like this

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def addwriter(request,name):
  logger.debug("the coming request is: {}, and the name is: {}".format(request, name))
  nimos = Writer(name=name);
  nimos.save();
  return render_to_response("addJournalist.html",{"name":nimos.name})
```

I think you just like @Rohan said, you send 3 request to this view. Your python code work correctly.

here is my naive test code

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Writer


class WriterTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_writer_name_function(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.client.get("/new/George/")
        writer_set = Writer.objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(writer_set.count(), 3)
```

PS: before add the logger code, make sure you have set up logging in django

Answer (score 1):

m sorry i know now the answer i simply included static files for css and imgs by a wrong way embedded in html so the browser made the request three times im very sorry for bothering you